# Rendering a lot of boost polygons

Tags: c++, opengl, boost, boost-geometry

I'm working on a CAD tool that needs to draw a lot of `boost::geometries` on a canvas (up to 3 million rectangles or a little bit more complex polygons).

In my implementation, I have a `std::vector<T>` where `T == boost::multipolygon`, that must be drawn on a canvas.

In the past, I've faced some memory and CPU issues using Qt's `QGraphicsItem`'s, and I would now like to avoid using such a library.

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to iterate through a vector of `boost::geometries` in order to render them on the screen, using OpenGL.

What do you suggest? Do you think there is a better way to keep my polygon data? (the polygon data is used in the other parts of the software as well, and not only during the rendering process).

Comment: consider going to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do a google search of Batch Processing or Batch Rendering; I think this will help significantly especially if you are using modern OpenGL 3.5 or greater with the use of GLSL. Creating a batch process or que to render vertices will help to maximize the amount of vertices to send to the renderer while minimizing the amount of CPU to GPU calls.

Comment: How dynamic are the polygon sizes?  Are you generally adding points or removing them?  How do you plan on triangulating the polygons, if needed?  Can you guarantee [convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon) and/or [simplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon)?  When you say "complex polygons" do you mean capital-C [Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_polygon)?  Do the polygons need to be filled?

Comment: They are constant polygons, obtained from a "library" of shapes. I think the triangularization is not necessary. Convexity: Yes, for the majority (>95% are simple rectangles). Simplicity: Yes, 100%. The most "complex" polygons are sets of stacked rectangles. Yes, they need to be filled.